# Why is the jquery script not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why is the jQuery script working in my jsfiddle but not in my page?

What I've done: Tried different versions of JQuery...made the script

So I have this test page:

### Head Part

```
   <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
           <style>

            select #canselect_code {
                width:200px;
                height:200px;
            }
            .fr {
                float:right;
            }
            .fl {
                float:left;
            }


        </style>

        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
    
    $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
    
});

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {

    $(this).next('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');

});

});
        </script>
       

</head>
```

### Body Part

```
 <div>
    <select id='canselect_code' name='canselect_code' multiple class='fl'>
        <option value='1'>toto</option>
        <option value='2'>titi</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' id='btnRight_code' value='  >  ' />
    <br>
    <input type='button' id='btnLeft_code' value='  <  ' />
    <select id='isselect_code' name='isselect_code' multiple class='fr'>
        <option value='3'>tata</option>
        <option value='4'>tutu</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7785m/)

Now my question is: Why is the code working in JsFiddle but not in my document?

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT: Added document ready function..still does not work!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Samuel Liew is right.
sometimes jquery conflict with the other jqueries.
to solve this problem you need to put them in such a order that they may not conflict with each other.
do one thing: open your application in google chrome and inspect bottom right corner with red marked errors.
which kind of error that is?

Comment: Failed to load resource file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined test.html:29
Failed to load resource

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
<script>
     jQuery.noConflict();
     // Use jQuery via jQuery() instead of via $()
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });  
</script>
```

Reason: "Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $".

Read full reason here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

If this solves your issue, it's likely another library is also using $.

Comment: indeed.. why?  :P

Comment: Thanking myself years later for this answer :D

Answer (score 9):

This works fine. just insert your jquery code in document.ready function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {   
    // your code here
 });

example:
```

### jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {   

      $('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {    
        $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');    
      });

      $('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
        $(this).next('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');
      });

    });
```

### html

```
    <div>
        <select id='canselect_code' name='canselect_code' multiple class='fl'>
            <option value='1'>toto</option>
            <option value='2'>titi</option>
        </select>
        <input type='button' id='btnRight_code' value='  >  ' />
        <br>
        <input type='button' id='btnLeft_code' value='  <  ' />
        <select id='isselect_code' name='isselect_code' multiple class='fr'>
            <option value='3'>tata</option>
            <option value='4'>tutu</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: js fiddle automatically calling our js code in onload event. but when we use in our document, we need to call that function in document onload function or document.ready function.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your script in the ready function. **jsFiddle does that automatically for you.**

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
        $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
    });

    $('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
        $(this).next('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');
    });
});
```

This is why you should not use third party tools unless you know what they automate/simplify for you.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but may help others whose jquery is not working properly, or working sometimes and not at other times.

This could be because your jquery has not yet loaded and you have started to interact with the page.  Either put jquery on top in head (probably not a very great idea) or use a loader or spinner to stop the user from interacting with the page until the entire jquery has loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Use `noConflict()` method

Ex: `jQuery.noConflict()`

and Use jQuery via `jQuery()` instead of via `$()`

Ex: `jQuery('#id').val();` instead of `$('#id').val();`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    do your codes here  it will work..
    type="text/javascript" is important for jquery 
<script>
```

Answer (score -2):

if you have some other scripts that conflicts with jQuery wrap your code with this

```
(function($) {
    //here is your code
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: the minus so far? any comments?)

Comment: You might want to use this:
$(function(){
   // jQuery methods go here...
});