# jquery not firing with code

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to put text after a input box. But it doesn't seem to be firing or working. Am I missing something here?

```
<script>
  $("#FormField_4").after('<div class="vt">As appears on ID.</div>');
</script>
```

I have tested this using chrome console and it works exactly as expected. I can also see the code in the source of the page.

Comment: You need to wrap that in document ready.

Comment: Is that script before or after the form field in the HTML? If it's before, you need to use `$(document).ready()` to wait for the rest ot the HTML to be loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the jquery script not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830689/why-is-the-jquery-script-not-working)

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#FormField_4").after('<div class="vt">As appears on ID.</div>');
});   and it still does not seem to work. I tried the other post you linked to before I posted. It didn't work. Sorry if you think its a duplicate post.

Comment: Does `id='formFIeld_4'` exist in your HTML? I'm assuming you are using inline JavaScript, so clearing your cache shouldn't be the issue. Do you have the jQuery Library `<script>` tag?

Comment: Yea,  And I have other straight line jquery in there as well that works. Like I said I can run the code through chrome console and it works perfect but if I try to actually put it in the page code it doesn't work. It's the strangest thing I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/tz9yagm4/

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#FormField_4").after('<div class="vt">As appears on ID.</div>');
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id ="FormField_4"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know why its not working. I thought it was me or something I was doing wrong but nothing seems to be working so the code i'm assuming it not wrong.

Comment: Can you provide exactly what you are writing

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#FormField_4").after('<div class="vt">As appears on ID.</div>');
});

</script>  i'm just trying to add some text after a input field.